# PHP Unit testing setting JWT token after login test completes

Tags: php, unit-testing, lumen

Hi I'm trying to set JWT token after the login test is complete in a global var and then extend all tests off of that class, now I'm not sure if I am even doing it right so any help is appreciated or documentation I could look up

```js
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

class AuthenticationTest extends TestCase {
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $token = '';

    /**
     * Register test user
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testRegister()
    {
        $this->json('post', '/auth/register', [
            'email' => Config::get('tests.email'),
            'password' => Config::get('tests.password'),
            'companyName' => Config::get('tests.companyName'),
            'firstname' => Config::get('tests.firstname'),
            'lastname' => Config::get('tests.lastname')
        ]);
        $this->assertEquals(200, $this->response->status());
        $this->seeJsonEquals([
            'message' => "Registration successful, please confirm email to login",
            'status'  => true,
        ]);
    }
    /**
     * Login test user
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testLogin()
    {
        $email = Config::get('tests.email');
        $password = Config::get('tests.password');
        $encryptedToken = base64_encode($email . ":" . $password);
        $this->json('post', 'auth/login', ['token' => $encryptedToken]);
        $this->assertEquals(200, $this->response->status());
        $this->seeJsonStructure([
            'token',
            'refresh',
            'status'
        ]);
        $content = json_decode($this->response->getContent());
        $this->assertObjectHasAttribute('token', $content);
        $this->token = $content->token;
        $this->token;

    }
}
?>
```

The login test works as it should but the token isn't being set for other tests that extend off of this test case ad use $this->token to send the JWT token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHPUnit creates a new instance of `AuthenticationTest` for every test method to run each test in isolation.

For tests that need an authenticated user, you have to obtain the token somehow. You could make an api request like you did in `testLogin`. A bit faster and less brittle way would be to create the token programatically using the same service as in your production code.

To reduce boilerplate, create a test case for tests with an authenticated and create the token in the `setup` method. Tests that extend from this class have the `token` property. Alternatively, you could also make this functionality a trait.

EDIT:

Here's a simple code example.

```
abstract class AuthenticatedUserTestCase extends TestCase
{
    protected function token(): string
    {
        $email          = Config::get('tests.email');
        $password       = Config::get('tests.password');
        $encryptedToken = base64_encode($email . ':' . $password);
        $response       = $this->json('post', 'auth/login', ['token' => $encryptedToken]);
        $content        = json_decode($response->getContent());

        if (!isset($content->token)) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Token missing in response');
        }

        return $content->token;
    }
}

final class UserProfileTest extends AuthenticatedUserTestCase
{
    public function test_that_user_can_access_their_profile_page()
    {
        $response = $this->json('get', '/user/profile', [], ['token' => $this->token()]);
        
        // ... assert stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: So if I was to put a setup method in the AuthenticaionTest or in each test case and just call the login API to get a JWT token back from it each time would that work

Comment: @ConorDonohoe Pretty much. I wouldn't probably do it in the `AuthenticationTest` though. I added an example to answer.

Comment: One more question is there a way I can write this function once in say the base TestCase and use it across different test cases in different files

Comment: Yes, sure. In my example I already used it in a different class (`UserProfileTest`). You can move the `token` method from the `AuthenticatedUserTestCase` to your base TestCase.